# Getting a Facebook OAuth problem with HTTP referer

Tags: php, facebook, http, oauth

I got an email today saying:

> In every case that we have examined,
> this information is passed via the
> HTTP Referer Header by the user's
> browser. This can happen when using
> our legacy authentication system and
> including ,  or 
> content from 3rd parties in the page
> that receives authentication data from
> Facebook. Our legacy mechanism passes
> authentication information in the URL
> query string which, if handled
> incorrectly, can be passed to 3rd
> parties by the browser. Our current
> OAuth 2.0 authentication system,
> released over a year ago, passes this
> information in the URL fragment, which
> is not passed to 3rd parties by the
> browser.

I'm a bit confused as the way I have integrated is using the PHP API using a similar response as per the example.php file:

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Here is how I'm making the request:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => FACEBOOKAPPID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOKSECRET,
    'cookie' => false,
));
$fb_session = $facebook->getSession();
$fb_me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($fb_session) {
    try {
        $fb_uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $fb_me = $facebook->api('/me');
        $fb_me['photo'] = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_uid.'/picture?type=large';
        $_SESSION['register_api'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['register_api_details'] = $fb_me;
        $_SESSION['register_api_user_id'] = $fb_uid;
        header_redirect(SITEURL.'/register');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
}
else{
    # LOGIN URL FOR FACE BOOK & request extra stuff
    $fb_login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms'=>'email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_website'));
    header_redirect($fb_login_url);
}
```

Everything is working fine, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong. As far as I was aware, I am using OAuth.

Comment: Hi David. If you still sign in here, would you close this question as "typo/unrepro"? I don't think it will help future readers, so we might as well try to clear it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that they were just about to release a new version of the API which solved this problem.